# ParseException when parsing 3 character abbreviated month using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing, parseexception

Here is my code,

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date dft  = (Date) format.parse("16-MAY-2018 09:30:22:000");
```

I am getting below exception

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "16-MAY-2018 09:30:22"

What's to be used to parse milliseconds?

Comment: Your pattern says: `MM`, your String has `MAY`. If you have a very close look, you can see that this does not exactly match. `16-05-2018 09:30:22` is the String you need for your pattern.

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) reveals that "Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number."

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca `MM` *does* imply that the month should be a number. "If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number." So for `MM`, the number of pattern letters is less than 3, so the month is interpreted as a number.

Comment: Also what no answer mentions to this point is that the parse will always fail if your `Locale` is not `Locale.English`or `Locale.English` is specified as second parameter for the `SimpleDateFormat`'s constructor.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using the long outdated `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes? I recommend you forget about them and instead use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern should be MMM because there are three characters in the month.

You should also prefer [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes to the ones you're currently using if you're on Java 8 or above:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy")
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .append(ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
    .toFormatter();

LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.parse("16-May-2018 09:30:22", formatter);
```

Comment: What about milliseconds ? I am not able to prase milliseconds

Comment: @zyanBillings `ISO_LOCAL_TIME` already includes an optional decimal point, with up to 9 digits for fractions of a second.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
                                        java.util.Date d1 =(java.util.Date)format.parse("03-MAY-2018 08:00:00:000 AM");
                                     timeFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"; `
I am trying like below and getting same exception

Comment: Have you ignored my advice about `java.time` or are you using <= Java 7?

Comment: @zyanBillings No big problem. `java.time` has been backported. All you need for Java 6 and 7 is [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Enjoy.

Comment: To parse uppercase `MAY` add a call to `parseCaseInsensitive` before the call to `appendPattern`.

Comment: Given that your month abbreviations are in English you should also specify an English-speaking locale. For example `.toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern: dd-**MMM**-yyyy HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

"16-MAY-2018 09:30:22" is not parsable with that time format. If you want to parse that you have to change date format to "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss". The double M is only for numbered months (so should be 05 for May).

Check the SimpleDateFormat javadoc for more details: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Date dft  = (Date) format.parse("16-05-2018 09:30:22");
```

OR change it to

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: After this I am getting below exception
>java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Comment: Please change your import statement to `import java.util.Date;`

Comment: Date class is provided by both `java.util.Date` and by `java.sql.Date`. You need to use the one from util package. That's the right one to use here.

Answer (score 0):

you are using dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss, so parsable is

```
16-05-2018 09:30:22
```

and if you want 16-MAY-2018 09:30:22 then use

```
dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
```